# How can I use catlina api of tomcat to access session administration

Tags: tomcat, servlets, java-ee-6, tomcat7

How can I use catlina api of tomcat to access session administration. I have a requirement  to invalidate session of other users from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer not to bind to Tomcat packages and get away with `javax.servlet` API as much as I can, for obvious reasons. Your task can be achieved by creating a session listener and keeping all sessions in a `WeakHashMap`, like so

```
<!-- your webapp's web.xml -->
<listener>
  <listener-class>path.to.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
   private static final Map<String, HttpSession> sessions = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<String, HttpSession>());

   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
      sessions.put(event.getSession().getId(), event.getSession());
   }

   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
      sessions.remove(event.getSession().getId());
   }
}
```

The rest is as easy as adding another method to iterate through all sessions and invalidate them.

Answer (score 0):

use session.invalidate method fro particular user like .

if you are setting an user in session.set attribute then get that particualr method from accessor method.

Use pojo beans for acessing it.

Before invalidating the session check it must be true or valid.